# How to use generic types in macro function arguments

Tags: c++, unit-testing, generics

I want to make a test library for c++

So I have defined this macro

```
#define TEST_CHECK(cond) check(cond,__FILE__,__LINE__,"%s",#cond)
```

And implemented `check(...)` as:

```
int check(int cond, const char* file, const char* line, const char* fmt, ...){
    // ...
    if(cond){printf("test passed");}
    else{ printf("test failed");}
    // ...
}
```

It is working okay, I can, for example use it as follows

```
TEST_CHECK(max(1,2)==1);
```

> test failed

```
TEST_CHECK(max(-2,-3)==-2);
```

> test passed

---

But now I would like to print the expected and the observed result, instead of only printing text failed.

So an execution example would be

```
TEST_CHECK(max(2,3),3);
```

> test failed: expected 3 but got 2

I could change my function to `check(int expected, int observed ...)` and it would work. But in that case I would be fitting only for INTEGER validation. I would also want to make this function useful for double,float, bool, char, char[], int[],...).

How could I solve this?

Comment: First of all, why are you creating your own test macros like this? There are plenty of unit-testing frameworks for both C and C++ which have the functionality that you need. Better to use them than to reinvent the wheel (and figure out all these things and remaking all te basic mistakes).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: Secondly, if you choose to still create your own macros, then I recommend that you create *different* macros for different things. Like the first that you have `TEST_CONDITION` or similar, and the second `TEST_EXPECTED`. Then you can use both as and when needed.

Comment: Unrelated, but since I see `__FILE__` ecc, consider `std::source_location` if you can use c++20

Comment: C++ or C? They are different languages.

Comment: A C solution can involve `_Generic`, but I'll   wait to find out which language OP really wants.

Comment: What you want is impossible. That's why all test frameworks have macros like `ASSERT_EQ`, `ASSERT_NE`, `ASSERT_LT` etc. with comparison operands provided separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template function.

```
template <typename T>
void check (T expected, T observed)
{
    if (expected == observed)
        std::cout << "Test passed\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Test failed: Expected " << expected 
                  << "but got " << failed << std::endl;
}
```